# Internet Connection sharing on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

My PC gets the Internet from USB tethering to my Mobile phone.I formed an 4-port Ethernet bridge and succeeded in sharing Internet.However, I noticed that all Ethernet devices must be assigned an IP in the range 192.168.137.2 - 245 to work. How to Enable DHCP on the Ethernet bridge ? If not, how to enable WiFi hotspot  from a USB Wireless adapter ? When I bridged the WiFi adapter to the Ethernet bridge,it has a static IP 192.168.137.1 as well and DHCP is disabled